# Remove background color in chartjs line chart

Tags: chart.js, ng2-charts, chartjs-2.6.0

I have setup my line chart like this:
[image: I want to remove the green color from the background and make it transparent]

**How can I remove the green color from the background and make it transparent**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set fill property as false in Dataset options

```
 datasets: [
    {
        label: "",
        fill: false,
        .....
        .......
        data: [65, 59, 80, 0, 56, 55, 40],
    }
]
```

You can refer this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/red_stapler/u5aanta8/1/

Also Reffer chartJs Docs
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html